# Does Asp.Net core 2.1 Scaffolding use Bootstrap 4 yet?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm still on ASP.Net core 2.0 and VS 15.6 that uses Bootstrap 3 for scaffolding. question to those who are using the new ASP.Net core 2.1 and VS 15.6, does the new version use Bootstrap 4 for scaffolding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not. I checked it right at this moment. It is still 3.3.7

Comment: @MotiKorets Yes it does provide an answer to the question. Not the best, but it is still an answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can update de scaffolding app to Angular 6 and Bootstrap 4 using Jason Taylor blog posts:

Update to Angular6

http://www.codingflow.net/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-2-1-with-angular-6-part-1-getting-started/

Update to Bootstrap 4

http://www.codingflow.net/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-2-1-with-angular-6-part-2-upgrading-to-bootstrap-4/